# How to share service connections in Golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm new to Go and looking at this the [elastic library](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) for go and in the Getting Started example it says "You typically create one client for your app."

What does that mean? Do you create a client in the your `main` function and somehow pass it to the functions with [context](https://blog.golang.org/context)? Do you create a global variable and assign it to the client, like this?

```
var (
  client *elastic.Client
)

func a() {
  client.Search()
}

func main() {
  c, err := elastic.NewClient()
  client = c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This gets into a topic that is kinda controversial in go: **dependency injection.**

Unlike some other languages, we don't usually believe in complicated IOC containers, xml config, and reflection based tools for this kind of thing. I merely follow a few simple principles:

1. Application packages and components should have all of their dependencies passed to them explicitly. Preferably as an interface type. If my `web` package needs a database connection, and an elastic client, it may have a function like `Serve(addr string, db database.DB, client *elastic.Client)` where `DB` is an interface type for my application's db.
2. The job of `main` is essentially to read configuration, create all shared components, and pass them to the various components:

   ```
   func main(){
     var config = readConfig() //flags, json, whatever
     var elastic = elastic.NewClient(config.whatever)
     var db = database.New(config.Connectionstring)

     //now start app components
     web.Serve(config.Addr, db, elastic)
   }
   ```

I find this pattern helps keep my packages separate yet inter-operable. I try to avoid package level variables for anything that needs to change from run to run.

Comment: Where can I learn more about this pattern? I'd love to see a project that follows it

Answer (score 1):

I would create special type that holds these objects.

```
type AppFactory struct {
  Client          *http.Client
  DatastoreClient *datastore.Client
  FileStorage     FileStorage
  DB              DB
}
```

or you can use context.Context

```
type key int
const clientKey key = 0

func NewContext(ctx context.Context, client *elastic.Client) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(ctx, clientKey, client)
}

func ClientFromContext(ctx context.Context) *elastic.Client {
    client := ctx.Value(clientKey).(*elastic.Client)
    return client
}
```

Personally, I would use context.Context because it is more universal solution.

I don't think it is a good idea to use global variables.
Very quickly it can become a problem.